# How to export first stage estimate into LaTeX output when using ivreg2?

Tags: latex, stata, overleaf

I'm running `ivreg2` in Stata and am unable to export the first-stage coefficient and sd into the LaTeX output. However, I can export the F-stat of IV in the first stage. I'm only interested in the IV estimate, so the 2SLS coefficient on the endogenous regressor being instrumented. In the reproducible example below, `weight` is an exogenous regressor.

```
*ssc install estout, replace
*ssc install ivreg2, replace

sysuse auto, clear
eststo clear

gen rep = (rep78 > = 4)
summ mpg
gen mpgx = (mpg > = `r(mean)')
summ trunk
gen trunkx = (trunk > = `r(mean)')
 
eststo: ivreg2 price weight (foreign = mpgx) if rep == 1 , savefirst first
estadd scalar fiv = e(F)

eststo: ivreg2 price weight (foreign = mpgx) if rep == 0 , savefirst first
estadd scalar fiv = e(F)

eststo: ivreg2 price weight (foreign = mpgx) if trunkx == 1 , savefirst first
estadd scalar fiv = e(F)

eststo: ivreg2 price weight (foreign = mpgx) if trunkx == 0 , savefirst first
estadd scalar fiv = e(F)


 esttab using "iv_test.tex", replace   ///
 b(3) se(3) star(* 0.10 ** 0.05 *** 0.01) ///
 label booktabs nonotes nomtitle collabels(none)  ///
 scalars("fiv IV F-stat")  ///
    keep(foreign) /// it's not allowing me to keep the first stage coef on mpgx
 mgroups("Repair" "Trunk", pattern(1 0 1 0) ///
 prefix(\multicolumn{@span}{c}{) suffix(}) span erepeat(\cmidrule(lr){@span}))
```

I will be grateful for any help!

Comment: For this to be reproducible, the user needs to install the community-contributed commands mentioned.